# react-redux connect giving undefined props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state-management, react-context

I am working with react-redux for state management and passing state store using `provider` but I dont know why it is comming as undefined in the consumer part
my provider component

```
  render(){
    return (
        <Provider store = {store} >
            <ApolloProvider client = {client} >
                  <div className="row">
                        <SideBar />
                        <Center />
                        <RightSlidePanel />
                  </div>
          </ApolloProvider>
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

the RightSLidePanel component

```
import { connect} from  'react-redux'
 class RightSlidePanel extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    console.log("inside connect " + this.props);
  }
//render method here

}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      loggedInUser : state.loggedInUser
    }

}
const mapDepatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  return {
    changeIsReduxWorking : answerTrueOrNot =>{
            dispatch({
              type : "CHANGE_REDUX_WORKING_STATUS",
              data : answerTrueOrNot
            });
    }
  }
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDepatchToProps
)(RightSlidePanel);
```

the result of the console.log is coming as `undefined`.

Comment: can you show how you are importing `RightSlidePanel` ?

Comment: @Sagiv like this :-  `import RightSlidePanel from './rightSlidePanel.js'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing props to super, because of that `props` is undefined there.

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    console.log("inside connect " + this.props);
  }
```

Comment: It worked . The dispatches and the state are accessable now but why in the console log its comming `[object object]`?

Comment: Because you are concatenating a string with your props. Is this intentional or do you want to do this instead: `console.log("inside connect ", this.props);`